# Need to backfill data into a Google Bigquery table that has Repeated Records

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Currently I have a table - Say **table_one**
Example Schema:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA2EP.png

```
| Field Name  | Type      | Mode     |
| ----------- | --------- |--------- |
| id          | STRING    | NULLABLE |
| entry       | RECORD    | REPEATED |
| entry. date | DATE      | NULLABLE |
| entry.date1 | STRING    | NULLABLE |
| entry.date2 | STRING    | NULLABLE |
| entry.date3 | STRING    | NULLABLE |
```

As the image shows the Record type can have multiple columns and this can be repeated.

Now I have another table - **table_two**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NalNa.png

```
| Field Name  | Type      | Mode     |
| ----------- | --------- |--------- |
| id          | STRING    | NULLABLE |
| entry       | RECORD    | REPEATED |
| entry .date | TIMESTAMP | NULLABLE |
| entry.date1 | STRING    | NULLABLE |
| entry.date2 | STRING    | NULLABLE |
| entry.date3 | STRING    | NULLABLE |
```

I need to backfill data from table_one to table_two

I have tried directly select the entry column but that does not seem to work.
And also the date column's datatype is changed hence i also need to cast it while backfilling data

I need a query that can backfill the data from table_one to table_two while casting the column **data** to timestamp while backfilling

Sample backfill SQL Code for other tables:

```
> INSERT INTO table_two(id, date, date2) SELECT id, CAST(date as
 timestamp), date2 from table_one
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) *(Please read and then replace the images with formatted text.)*